# Get the last line for a specific variable

Tags: postgresql-9.4

I am applying a windows function similar to the query on the example below. I would like to know how can I extract only the last row for each depname. I need all the lines on the query or else the sum won't be correct. I am thinking of applying an outter query to this one, extracting the last line for each depname but I do not know how to do it. I tried using FETCH LAST but it did not work. Can anyone help me? Thank you

```
QUERY:
    SELECT depname, empno, salary,
           sum(salary) OVER (PARTITION BY depname ORDER BY salary DESC)
    FROM empsalary;


RESULT:
      depname  | empno | salary | sum
    -----------+-------+--------+------
     develop   |     8 |   6000 |  6000
     develop   |    10 |   5200 | 11200
     develop   |    11 |   5200 | 16400
     personnel |     2 |   3900 |  3900
     personnel |     5 |   3500 |  7400
     sales     |     1 |   5000 |  5000
     sales     |     4 |   4800 |  9800
     sales     |     3 |   4800 | 14600
```